# Why does my Visual Project only run in Debug Mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, web-config, visual-web-gui

I got an old Visual Studio project which was migrated in another webserver.
The project is written in C# and works with Visual WebGui (.wgx).
The project creates some forms and the web server load a .wgx file.

**Now the problem:**

When I start debugging the project it works on the Visual Studio Development Server (localhost:62358/frm_main.wgx).

But when I want to load the frm_main.wgx on the webserver localhost:85/frm_main.wgx, it says Error 404.0.

It is a Windows Server 2008 with an IIS7 web server running.
I already checked the web.config.
And checked the httphandler section to handle .wgx files.

Comment: As far as I know, the 404 error means the page not found. I suggest you could firstly check the  localhost:85 url is right to locate your application and check the application root path has the wgx file. Then I suggest you could check the web.config file to make sure there is not other config like url rewrite which will redirect the request to another url.

Comment: the location is right and also no rewrite to another url.
the tricky thing with .wgx is, that the Gizmox(...)**.dll** library compile a **.cs** file into a **.wgx** file. This is really special for visual webgui. 
On the webserver IIS7 is a handler mapping for .wgx configured. This handler calls the aspnet_isapi.dll. 
I guess there is something wrong with the mapping.

Comment: I changed the .Net Framework from v2 to v4. Now it works!
this link was also helpfull: https://code.stylenet.ca/deploying-net-40-applications-using-iis-7x/